# Drawing a opacity radial gradient on a HTML canvas and use it as a background

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, radial-gradients

I'm looking for a way to make a canvas object look like this: http://www.onetuts.com/attachments/2010/05/07/1_201005072156152XYem.jpg

The gradient should be going from rgba(0,0,0,0.8) to rgba(0,0,0,0.2) but i don't get the canvas to be 1280x720px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradient in your example image is different - from `0x828282` to `0x0a0a0a`. Check this out:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var grd = cxt.createRadialGradient(150, 150, 0, 150, 150, 150);

grd.addColorStop(0, "#828282");
grd.addColorStop(1, "#0a0a0a");
cxt.fillStyle = grd;
cxt.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Works good for me, but isn't as big as i was thinking. it should be 1280x720px and instead of the HEX values, i wanna use      rgba(130,130,130,0.2) etc.

Comment: You can write `rgba(130,130,130,255)` instead of `#828282` in function addColorStop(). Also just change sizes as you need in `width="300" height="300"` and `cxt.fillRect(0,0,300,300);`. Also please don't forget to mark answer as accepted if you feel that it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm on this exact same quest and Google has already indexed this 7 hours old page.  Amazing.  Would you mind holding my hand through the createRadialGradient arguments?

Comment: Here is good [canvas documentation](http://www.openspc2.org/HTML/en/appendix/canvas_param/canvas/createRadialGradient/index.html)

Comment: @JGrubb `createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)`: `x0, y0` is the center of circle A with a radius of `r0`; `x1, y1` is the center of circle B with a radius of `r1`. The edge of circle A will be the color at stop 0, fading to the color at stop 1 at the edge of circle B. See the [WhatWG docs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-createradialgradient) for more details.